# MudBlazor, DataGrid Filter change language

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I would like to change the language used in the labels of the filters of the DataGrid. By default the labels are in English and I would like to have them in German.

[image: Filter in MudBlazor]

I have tried to change the general language of the application in the `programme.cs` with this line:

`app.UseRequestLocalization("de");`

Comment: Please try `app.UseRequestLocalization("de-DE");`

Comment: In my opinion, it's a helpful link for blazor localization. https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/common/localization#:~:text=Localization%20of%20Blazor%20Components&text=Localization%20is%20the%20process%20of,different%20languages%20for%20specific%20cultures.

Comment: @AlirezaK I have now tested it out. Unfortunately, the language has not changed.

Answer (score 1):

i got solver!!!

1 - 1 Update your version of Mudblazor

2 - put the following line in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<MudLocalizer, CustomMudLocalizerImpl>();
```

3 - Create a class named CustomMudLocalizerImpl and paste the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using MudBlazor;

    internal class CustomMudLocalizerImpl : MudLocalizer
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> _localization;

        public CustomMudLocalizerImpl()
        {
            _localization = new()
        {

            { "MudDataGrid.AddFilter", "Adicionar filtro" },
            { "MudDataGrid.Apply", "Aplicar" },
            { "MudDataGrid.Cancel", "Cancelar" },
            { "MudDataGrid.Clear", "Limpar" },
            { "MudDataGrid.CollapseAllGroups", "Recolher todos os grupos" },
            { "MudDataGrid.Column", "Coluna" },
            { "MudDataGrid.Columns", "Colunas" },
            { "MudDataGrid.contains", "Contem" },
            { "MudDataGrid.ends with", "Termina com" },
            { "MudDataGrid.equals", "Igual" },
            { "MudDataGrid.ExpandAllGroups", "Expandir todos os grupos" },
            { "MudDataGrid.Filter", "Filtro" },
            { "MudDataGrid.False", "Falso" },
            { "MudDataGrid.FilterValue", "Valor filtro" },
            { "MudDataGrid.Group", "Grupo" },
            { "MudDataGrid.Hide", "Esconder" },
            { "MudDataGrid.HideAll", "Esconder todos" },
            { "MudDataGrid.is", "é" },
            { "MudDataGrid.is after", "é após" },
            { "MudDataGrid.is before", "é antes" },
            { "MudDataGrid.is empty", "é vazio" },
            { "MudDataGrid.is not", "Não é" },
            { "MudDataGrid.is not empty", "Não é vazio" },
            { "MudDataGrid.is on or after", "está ligado ou após" },
            { "MudDataGrid.is on or before", "está ligado ou antes" },
            { "MudDataGrid.not contains", "não contém" },
            { "MudDataGrid.not equals", "não é igual" },
            { "MudDataGrid.Operator", "Operador" },
            { "MudDataGrid.RefreshData", "Atualizar dados" },
            { "MudDataGrid.Save", "Salvar" },
            { "MudDataGrid.ShowAll", "Mostrar tudo" },
            { "MudDataGrid.starts with", "Começa com" },
            { "MudDataGrid.True", "Verdadeiro" },
            { "MudDataGrid.Ungroup", "Desagrupar" },
            { "MudDataGrid.Unsort", "Ordenar" },
            { "MudDataGrid.Value", "Valor" }
        };
        }

        public override LocalizedString this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Parent.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
                if (currentCulture.Equals("pt", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    && _localization.TryGetValue(key, out var res))
                {
                    return new(key, res);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new(key, key, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

4 - Translate and place your "culture",You can put a breakpoint and see the translation, the moment you click on the filter

Result:
[image]

Comment: What about blazor wasm hosted project that has 3 project : server, client, shared. I test your injection in program.cs and your DictionaryMudLocalizer class but it don't work. I want to replace Unsort to Remove Sort a MudDataGrid column.
Also write this issue : https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/7374